# Create tab and send a message from popup.html

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to create a tab and send a message to it from popup.html

I can create a tab with `chrome.tabs.create` and can get the tab's `id`, but while the `tab.status` is `loading` the messaging is not possible.

Also it is not possible to wait until `chrome.tabs.get` returns `status=complete` because callback function doesn't execute (bug?)

I can't think another possibility to send a message to a tab from popup.html.

Please help :)

Comment: Listen to `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` and send the message when the status becomes 'complete'.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But "onUpdated" executes only once with status=loading. I think because popup.html is destroyed after that.